# Emitter current and Early effect

Tags: transistors, current, semiconductors, biasing

I know that due to Early effect in a npn transistor the effective base width reduces.However I can't understand how this will lead to  an increase in emitter current.
Some sources say that the charge concentration gradient increases due to this Early effect and hence the increase in emitter current but how can the charge gradient increase since that is determined by doping.
. Can any one please explain it then.
Any help will be appreciated
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: How are your search skills ? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22early+effect%22+current

Comment: Thank you. I am new here. I'll look up the link

Comment: There were 200 results, not sure why you think 201 explanations will help https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/231474/bjt-gain-width-of-base-region-vs-collector-current

Comment: I thought you suggested me to check them up

Comment: For VBE=const (externally created) the current IE will be constant. Due to the shrinking effect of the depletion zone, the base current reduces (rising Vce) and the collector current increases correpondingly.

Comment: @LvW thank you but The plot shows the increase in emitter current not the collector current.

Comment: Yes - I know. But I do not blindly trust any plots without knowing the source. I have seen to many wrong statements/formulas in textbooks and other publications.

Comment: @YasirSadiq I was hinting at you to search harder, I just responded quick to show it wasn't hard and besides I saw LvW's answer and he has similar deep experience as myself but better on this question.

Comment: @LvW - both the collector current and the emitter current will increase. If Vbe is constant the base current will also increase.

Comment: As VCE increases Hfe will also increase due to less recombination occurring in the thinner base region.

Comment: @LvW --"Yes - I know. But I do not blindly trust any plots without knowing the source. I have seen to many wrong statements/formulas in textbooks and other publications" the plot is from a well known book by boylestad and nashelsky.

Comment: OK - I agree to Kevin White. I think he is referring to the contribution of the inverting mode to the total IE current . Yes - it is true that there is - indeed - a certain dependence of this part on the CB voltage.

Comment: @Yasir Sadiq... I also agree that the figure you have shown comes from a well-known book (Boylestad and Co.). Hower, I suppose the shown dependence of IE on VCB is unrealistic (enlarged) - in comparison to the influence on IC. In this context, the authors state somewhat later (see figure 3.10a): "In fact, increasing levels of
VCB have such a small effect on the characteristics that as a first approximation the
change due to changes in VCB can be ignored"....

Comment: @LvW i agree ,but I'm trying to understand what causes the variation of emitter current with the base collector voltage irrespective of how small the variation is ,and until now i cannot understand it.

Comment: I think, it is well explained in the mentioned book. Normally, we speak only about the electrons from E to C (for npn transistors). This forms the major part of the curent IE. But there is a small second part contributing to the emitter current consisting of holes travelling the opposite way (from C to E). And this part is, of course, influenced by VCB (which changes when VCE changes).

Comment: @LvW as we increase Vcb in a npn transistor how does this increase the hole current towards the emitter?

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to explain you in a simple case:

You agree that on increasing Collector Base voltage, Emitter Current increases and width of the Base also decreases.
Now consider this: We have a recombination factor (alpha) which says that Some of the Majority Carriers (Which Constitute the current, not majority carriers w.r.t base) recombine with Minority carriers present in the Base and hence we receive a lesser current in Collector (in case of pnp, also pnp/npn doesn't matter for this explanation).

Thats why we have Ic = (alpha)*Ie

Now reduction in the base width due to the increase in collector base voltage which
increases reverse bias and thus increase the depletion region between collector base and eating up some space of the tiny base region thus it also means that carriers present in the base which recombine with Collector current also reduce in the base region. Now here recombination factor will point more towards 1 than it was pointing previously with less Collector Base voltage. Thus we will be getting higher Emitter current in comparison of previous one.

But it can be as high as Ic=Ie, when alpha = 1 (in ideal case) never more than that.

Answer (score 0):

following up on comment of "LvW", the mechanism would predict the highest_Beta transistors will have the least Early Effect (have the flattest I_out).

And because there is a small region of bulk silicon between the base contact for metal and the actual base region that is sandwiched between emitter and collector, with the Ibase * R_bulk_base == voltage varying as Ibase varies, it sees the LOWER NOISE transistors (which have lower R_bulk_base) will have lower Early Effect.

I realize the parameters we use are Abstractions, are parts of modeling.

SUMMARY: I'm thinking high_beta low_noise transistors will be the best current sources.

Comment: I fail to understand how this is related to my question.